# Same project in multiple ClickOnce applications

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, clickonce

I am publishing two ClickOnce applications `Foo` and `Bar` (available online only). The applications are made in C#. In the solution Foo and Bar they contain the exact same project which has references to a bunch of external .dll-files.

I have added these external .dll-files to the StartUp project in the solution of Foo and Bar in Visual Studio 2013, so that they will be included among the ClickOnce-files when I publish the applications. It works fine as long as there's only Foo deployed, but when I deploy Bar and start switching between them, they will have to re-download the .dll-files every single time.

So my question is: How can I somehow use the same project with references to external .dll-files in both `Foo` and `Bar`, without having to download the external .dll-files every time I switch between the applications?

**Solution:** The problem wasn't about the project as I suspected, but the external dlls being too big, so that two applications (online only) with these dlls was exceeding the ClickOnce cache quota for online applications. The easiest solution for me  was to make the ClickOnce applications available offline as well (so that it's not a part of the casche quota)

Comment: I don't think you can, as a "available online-only" ClickOnce project requires all components to be downloaded every time the application starts. You could consider making them available offline, too, so the download is only performed once. You could try to install the common components to the GAC in advance, but that contradicts the per-user installation concept of ClickOnce and makes updates difficult.

Comment: If I choose "available online only", the files will still be stored locally on the machine when I start `Foo`. What I believe happens is that when I start `Bar`, it will notice that the external .dlls has a different signature of some kind than the ones already stored locally and that's probably why the files will be downloaded again and replace the already stored ones. Then when I start `Foo` again, the same thing will happen (the files will be downloaded and replaced again)

Comment: I doubt that - it wouldn't make sense. If you have an offline ClickOnce application, the installation folders in the user's profile are separated and all required components would be copied into their respective folders. Why should there be some common storage of online-deployed applications?

Comment: I believe there's a common storage because it's the same project in both applications and because it has to re-download the files when I switch applications. As long as I'm only using `Foo` it will reuse the downloaded files every time (no download when I start), but when I start `Bar`, and then start `Foo` again it no longer recognizes that the files are already downloaded and start to download them again

Comment: Seems I was wrong - but this answers your question. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/267k390a.aspx

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response! I believe my problem isn't about the project as I suspected, but that it is about the external dlls being pretty big, and that two applications with these dlls will exceed the ClickOnce cache quota for online applications. So I'm guessing the easiest solution for me would be to either increase the quota on the clients or make the ClickOnce available offline as well (so that it's not a part of the casche quota)